# magento 2: Customize collection of product not effecting in layer & toolbar area

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, product-list, toolbar

I extend the collection query using event '`catalog_block_product_list_collection`'. Query displaying proper data, as well as showing proper record in product list page.
But same collection is not loading for layer & toolbar section.

here is my code

**events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_block_product_list_collection">
        <observer name="review" instance="PR\Catalog\Observer\CatalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtmlObserver" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**CatalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtmlObserver.php**

```
namespace PR\Catalog\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CatalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtmlObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Review model
     *
     * @var \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory
     */
    protected $_vendorProductFactory;

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $productCollection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        if ($productCollection instanceof \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection) {

           $productCollection->getSelect()->join(array(
                    'vendor_product' =>  'pr_vendor_product'), 
                    "e.entity_id = vendor_product.marketplace_product_id and vendor_product.status = 1", 
                    array('vendor_product.*')
                    );
            $productCollection->getSelect()->group('marketplace_product_id');
        }         
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: just curious. does it work if you disable the `CatalogSearch` module?

Comment: Awesome trick. When disabled `Magento_CatalogSearch`,  the layer navigation collection & product collection both seems proper. Please suggest me a whole punch  so I can achieve it without disable `catalogSearch`  module.

Comment: I had this problem when trying to build an extension that affected the layered nav and I was curious if it's the same for you. Unfortunately I don't have a solution. Apparently the search module rewrites something in the catalog module but I don't know what.

Comment: @Marius did you found any solution for layered navigation when product collection is customized on category page

Comment: @Marius did you found any solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: No. I did not. I didn't even look further.

Comment: @Praful Rajput did you found any solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: @omelandr not yet.

Answer (score -1):

I successfully applied my custom product collection on category page's layered navigation and toolbar.

For example, I am fetching the collection of those products whose price is less than 100.

**Step 1:** Add below code snippet

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer">
        <plugin name="custom_product_model_layer" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Layer" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="custom_product_toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Toolbar" />
    </type>

    <virtualType name="categoryFilterList" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="attribute" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute</item>
                <item name="price" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Price</item>
                <item name="decimal" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Decimal</item>
                <item name="category" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Category</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

</config>
```

**Step 2:** Create plugin for product collection

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Layer.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
class Layer
{
  public function aroundGetProductCollection(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject,
    \Closure $proceed
  ) {

    $result = $proceed();
    $result->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('lt' => 100));
    return $result;
  }
}
```

**Step 3:** Create plugin for toolbar

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Toolbar.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
class Toolbar
{

  protected $_objectManager;
  protected $request;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
  ) {
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    $this->request = $request;
  }

  public function aroundSetCollection(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $request
  ) {
    $result = $proceed($request);

    $this->_collection = $request;
    $category = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
    if($category)
    {
      $page = $this->request->getParam('p');
      if($page == '')
      {
        $page = 1;
      }
      $this->_collection->getCurPage();
      $this->_collection->setCurPage($page);  
    }
    else
    {
      $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());
    }

    return $result;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but It is not working properly. 
The layered navigation is not showing correct filters as per the loaded product collection.
For Ex. In product collection there is no "Color" attribute in any product, still It is showing color filter in layered navigation, which is not correct.
Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: hello @Dinesh, is this working for you?

Comment: Yes it was working for me. Many new magento versions have been released after I posted this answer so there might be some changes in the code of new version. I have not checked it with latest version of Magento.