# magento2 customize collection of product not effecting in layer & toolbar

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I extend the collection using event 'catalog_block_product_list_collection'. Query displaying proper data, as well as showing proper record in product list page. But same collection is not loading for layer & toolbar section.
I have [the same problem](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112491/magento-2-customize-collection-of-product-not-effecting-in-layer-toolbar-area)

How i can fix it problem?

Answer (score 0):

I successfully applied my custom product collection on category page's layered navigation and toolbar.

For example, I am fetching the collection of those products whose price is less than 100.

**Step 1:** Add below code snippet

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer">
        <plugin name="custom_product_model_layer" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Layer" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="custom_product_toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Toolbar" />
    </type>

    <virtualType name="categoryFilterList" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="attribute" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute</item>
                <item name="price" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Price</item>
                <item name="decimal" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Decimal</item>
                <item name="category" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Category</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

</config>
```

**Step 2:** Create plugin for product collection

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Layer.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
class Layer
{
  public function aroundGetProductCollection(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject,
    \Closure $proceed
  ) {

    $result = $proceed();
    $result->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('lt' => 100));
    return $result;
  }
}
```

**Step 3:** Create plugin for toolbar

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Toolbar.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
class Toolbar
{

  protected $_objectManager;
  protected $request;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
  ) {
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    $this->request = $request;
  }

  public function aroundSetCollection(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $request
  ) {
    $result = $proceed($request);

    $this->_collection = $request;
    $category = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
    if($category)
    {
      $page = $this->request->getParam('p');
      if($page == '')
      {
        $page = 1;
      }
      $this->_collection->getCurPage();
      $this->_collection->setCurPage($page);  
    }
    else
    {
      $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());
    }

    return $result;
  }

}
```